# Creating a new TimerTask from a separate class, JAVA

Tags: java, class, timer, mouseevent, timertask

The primary chunk of my code is `presentationController` (extends JFrame).  Within that, I create an object of type

`scrollPane = projectsScrollPane();` (extends JScrollPane).

I also create an object of type `presentation`.

The object `scrollPane` has

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new velocityCalc();
```

where velocityCalc is written as

```
public class velocityCalc extends TimerTask {... do stuff ...}
```

Within the `presentation` object, I cancel said timer, and later would like to renew it, but am unable to do so.

Canceling looks like:

```
presentationController.scrollPane.task.cancel;
```

which works as expected.  Creating a new task looks like:

```
presentationController.scrollPane.task = new presentationController.scrollPane.velocityCalc();
presentationController.scrollPane.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(presentationController.scrollPane.task, 0, 30);
```

but the portion after the equals sign in the first line is underlined in red (error), and asks me to

```
"Create class 'velocityCalc' in package 'presentationController.scrollPane'"
```

The two lines of code are within a mouseListener (mouseReleased).

This code was working perfectly before, but that was when all the code was contained within `presentationController`.  I have since then moved the `Timer` and `TimerTask` to `projectScrollPane` and the controlling lines of code to `presentation`, as described above.

Any thoughts?  Hopefully this has been clear enough!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - SOLUTION:

I created a method within `projectsScrollPane` that renews the `task` and now it works fine.  Probably how I should have done it in the first place, rather than having everything public.

```
public void createTimer(){
    task = new velocityCalc();
}
```

Comment: I think you want `presentationController.scrollPane.new velocityCalc()`. (Not sure, because you are ignoring the standard Java convention of uppercase class names and lowercase variable names).

Comment: sorry about the convention thing.  Those aren't the actual class names I am using, I replaced them in the question for simplicity sake - my bad!

Comment: Russell, I just tried your fix and it also worked!  Thanks!